# How to ignore src folder from package

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app and below is the folder structure.

```
app
|--node_modules
    |--somepackage/src
|--src
```

I am packaging this app using electron-packager, so I tried to ignore root level src folder by executing the below command.

```
"scripts": {
       "pack": "rimraf ./packaged/ && electron-packager . Test.Client --app-version=0.0.1 --prune --out=packaged --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite --ignore=webpack.config.js --ignore=/src 
  },
```

but here the problem is my node_modules also have some packages which contains src folder and those src folders are also getting ignored by above --ignore=/src statment.

Comment: That src in node_modules are also kind of no use because those packages must be having builds to facilitate the execution.

Comment: yes, but I am using logstash-client package and which is asking for debug module dependency inside src folder. If I remove --ignore statement my packaged application works.

Comment: Title sounds like the opposite of what OP asks. Maybe "how to _not_ ignore package src folder"?..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default, `electron-packager` is expecting a *regular expression* for the `--ignore` flag, so you may want to try `--ignore=^/src` to restrict the pattern to the root level...

Reference:

[electron-packager API option: ignore](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#ignore)

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. Thanks for looking into it and it's working as expected.