# Electron packager ignore folder contents from the root level

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I am trying to use electron-packager to package an electron app. When packaging my app I want to ignore the entire contents of certain folders. Using the `--ignore` flag you can pass a regular expression to electron-packager to tell it to ignore matches.

My folder structure looks like

```
app
|--build
|--node_modules
|--src
index.html
main.js
package.json
```

Using the method from the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524561/how-to-ignore-src-folder-from-package) I prepended my expression with `^` to restrict the pattern to the root level.

```
let execArgs = `npx electron-packager ./ "${productName}"`
    + ` --platform=win32`
    + ` --out=${outPath}`
    + ' --ignore=^/build';
execSync(execArgs);
```

However, electron-packager appears to still be ignoring more than just the specific folders. If I try running the packaged app I get the error `Error: Cannot find module '../helpers/buildURL'`. The full relative path of this file is `./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/buildURL.js`.

If I comment out the line ignoring the build folder, I no longer get the error above.

```
// + ' --ignore=^/build'
```

How can I make electron-packager ignore specific folders and their contents from the root level?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all I had to do was surround my argument in quotes.

```
+ ' --ignore="^/build"';
```

I'm not sure why this made a difference, since my argument does not include any spaces, but when I surrounded it in quotes the expression ignored only the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this script to ignore files when I package an electron app

script{"electron-build":"electron-packager . MYAPP --ignore build/* }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).